# Calculate coordinates from a distance in mm

Tags: c, math, latitude-longitude

I'm writing a piece of software which is responsible for logging the position of certain machine parts.

Now this is the case:

- There is 1 RTK fixed GPS receiver (+/- 2cm accuracy), fixed on the machine. The heading is calculated using 2 different locations
- There are 2 arms (left and right arm) on the machine that can rotate independent of each other outwards or inwards
- There is 1 arm (mid arm) with a fixed location on the machine

What I Already have:

A piece of software which calculates the location of the outer location of the arms (this works like a charm). This produces a shapefile as logfile in which the location of the arms are visible and this works good for every heading.

The problem is:

The algorithm is calculating the location of the arms using the delta X and delta Y distances in mm. 
My assumption was that the longitude 0.00000001 is equal to 1.1 mm on the X axis ([source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude)). Boy, what was I wrong...

When the shapefile that is generated is being measured using a shapefile viewer it returnes 2,19 meter instead of the calculated 3,25. Note that this is on the latitude 52.810146939 (Northern Hemisphere).

Thus the question:

Has anybody any idea how a formula can be formed that takes a latitude or longitude as starting point and a distance in [mm] and then returnes the corrected latitude or longitude? Or how I can calcuate the relative delta coordinates values to sum them with the Original coordinates?

I've got a snippet of the code:

```
Armlocations->leftarm.locationX = ownLocation.locationX + MM_TO_COOR(deltaX);
Armlocations->leftarm.locationY = ownLocation.locationY + MM_TO_COOR(deltaY);
```

deltaX and deltaY are the distances in mm that should be added to the coordinate. The macro MM_TO_COOR is this:

```
#define COOR_TO_MM(x)   ((x) * 110000000)
#define MM_TO_COOR(x)   ((x) / 110000000)
```

The question is not about programming -> I got that going for me, but more about the math involved to this.

Comment: Way too broad for SO. Write some code and we will help you.

Comment: `Has anybody any idea how a formula can be formed that takes a latitude or longitude as starting point and a distance in [mm] and then returnes the corrected latitude or longitude?` There are more than one solution to this. Can you give an example how the data is given?

Comment: It seems more like a math problem than a programming problem.

Comment: I actually is a math problem. I'll edit the tags but I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Given that a GPS has an accuracy of roughly +/-4000mm, you better hand over this project to a professional instead...

Comment: You may however be able to get some sort of accuracy with 3 axis accelerometers + gyro, nowadays available in MEMS.

Comment: @Lundin The location is being fixed using RTK. The accuracy is about +/- 2cm. I've edited the question for future replies.

Comment: I'd be wary of any conversion done using macros. There's no guarantee that the calculation is going to be performed using the data type you expect. This, rounding errors may surprise you.

Comment: A reading of [Haversine formula - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure this is not the right place, it might be a better fit to use https://gis.stackexchange.com.

About the latitude, it is always (about) 111 km per degree, so .00000001° (1E-8°) should indeed be 1.1 mm in y direction.

The relation for the longitude indeed depends on your current latitude: here, the factor per degree is 111 km multiplied by cos(latitude). In your case, that would (on a spherical earth) make a factor of 0.60445804192912, resulting in 67.1 km per degree or .671 mm per 1E-8°. On our earch, being flattened at the poles, the value is slightly different, but should be about the same (I cannot, however, tell how big the error is.)

Are you sure that your GPS device has this high resolution of several mm?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sure the GPS device has this resolution (it's RKT fixed using a base station and the accuracy is about +/- 2cm, small enough for this application)
Sorry for the misplacement, next time I'll put it in the right place.

Comment: You can't just use `cos()` like that unless you have a spherical Earth.  The Earth I know is somewhat oblate.

Comment: I just realised you where talking about a factor. Not the actual distance. I did the math and it seems to be pretty accurate (accurate enough :) ). Thanks!!

Comment: @TobySpeight You are right, taking into account that the precision I gave is quite high. But my calculation can be taken as a first approach.